# How Can I make a C# Windows Form Overlap in a Sidebar form?

Tags: c#

So, how can I make a Windows form, come onto the current form as a Sidebar instead of full form?

For example, I have Form 1 with a button named Sidebar, I press that button and Form2 comes and overlaps Form 1 as a Sidebar on the left? I know I can do it with the entire Computer Screen, but I just want it within the Application itself.

Comment: sounds like you need a User Control rather than a second form

Comment: Agreed. UserControl would make sense. You could do it with a borderless form, though.  Just set [TopLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel?view=net-5.0) to false and add the child form to the parent form like a normal control with `Controls.Add()`, possibly setting `Dock` to the right side.